# Identify a fried capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, repair

I am trying to clearly identify a fried ceramic capacitor in order to replace it. By chance, I could take a picture on another device of the same type:

[image: capacitor]

So far what I found after some search:

- I suppose that "101 K" is 100 pF +/- 10%.
- SL2KV (or is it SL2KY?) might be: dielectric = SL, max voltage = 2kV ?
- 6D from "9 6 D" might be "2016 december/january" as it is written on some Murata capacitors.
- Leads have "outside kinks" and 5 mm spacing. Diameter is around 6 mm.

The problem is that, when searching for this kind of component on Digikey, Farnell or Radiospares, there is either too many choices or not enough. I cannot find, for instance, what is the constructor or if it is single or multilayer.

More detail: I am trying to repair a TV whose stopped working, probably because of a lightning surge. The power supply board is showing 2 fried components: this one and a resistor I could easily identify. I hope by replacing these 2 components that the board will work again.

Comment: @calendoa .You may find that the surge has taken out more than the capacitor .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks like CX or CY typically applied in between L and N or L and gnd or N and gnd. The gnd is the low voltage side of the power supply.

Normally these caps are purposed for electromagnetic noise suppression. They do this by provide very low impedance path for very high frequency harmonic noise so that these noise are diverted away from sensitive electronics.

What is important for you to note when replacing these capacitor are simply the capacitance value (100pF) and their voltage rating (2000V).

For the repairing you are trying to do, pls do check all semiconductor components around the area because most of the time, these will go bad too, especially the high voltage switching IC.

Comment: If it is Y rated, then the replacement should be Y rated as well.  Same goes for X rated.  Those ratings are for the user's safety.